# Can anyone help me with a command line to convert .asf to .mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the command line `ffmpeg -i test1.asf -c:v libx264 -strict -2 test1.mp4` but I get the below error 'test.asf: Invalid data found when processing input'

Any suggestions, please?

thank you

Comment: Do you have any problem with samples from https://filesamples.com/formats/asf? the conversions are doing fine on colab.

Comment: sounds like something wrong with your input file. Try `ffprobe test1.asf` and see what it says.